# Convert VB.NET 2005 project to C# 2008 Project

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Is there a tool to convert a VB.NET 2005 project to a C# 2008 project. I am trying to convert our project to VS 2008 and mostly port all the vb.NET code in some projects to C# 3.0/3.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check out [SharpDevelop](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/articles/FeatureTourCodeConversion.aspx).  It's an open source .NET development environment.
SharpDevelop has some code conversion built in.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar decision to make with a VB.net project. 
Solution was a compromise, I decided to run with dual VB and C#.

Upgrading VB.NET 2005 to 2008 is easy bit.

Added CSharp and VB folders to App_Code and

```
<codeSubDirectories>
<add directoryName="CSharp" />
<add directoryName="VB" />
</codeSubDirectories>
```

to compilation section of web.config

As Kev says, it's not as straight forward as you might expect, and you will likely run into unexpected issues , that make running with dual language support the best solution

I know this doesn't directly answer the question, but it's an alternative approach

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this.

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Try to google term "convert vb.net project to c# project", you will find a couple of options there.

Answer (score 1):

There's a tool on CodeProject called [GBVB (Goodbye VB)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/gbvb.aspx) that purports to 'flawlessly' convert VB.NET code to C# code. However the author does add a number of caveats such as the problems with ambiguous code, optional parameters etc.

Another approach could be to use [Denis Bauer's Reflector.FileDisassembler](http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx) .NET Reflector [add-in](http://www.codeplex.com/reflectoraddins) and disassemble the compiled assemblies back to C#.

Handling .aspx/.asmx pages and their code-behind files would probably be a special case because you'd need to manually change the `<%@ Page Codebehind="Default.aspx.cs" %>` directives to point to the correct source files.

Automatic VB.NET to C# conversion isn't really as straight forward as it initially appears to be. I've been here before and gave up on a fairly large project, there's a lot of fiddling about with specific edge cases where the translation either wouldn't compile or produced unexpected behaviour at runtime.  I elected to go for a dual language solution where all new code was written in C# and older VB.NET code was ported gradually over time.

Answer (score 1):

hi this code answer not

```
public student ()
        {}
        private string code;
            private string name;
        public string code()
        { 
        set (code=Value);
            Get return code;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Telerik has a [converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) you might want to take a look at.

Comment: I am looking to convert the whole project. Instead of some files.

Answer (score 0):

Since others have mentioned online conversion tools I've found [www.carlosag.net](http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/CodeTranslator/) to work the best for my code.  Maybe b/c I work other 3rd party API's but it seems like a lot of the other online converter just error out if they hit a line they can't convert.

Answer (score 0):

SharpDevelop is quite good, but at my company we've found VBConversions to provide a much more complete conversion. It's a commerical app though, but for the time saved over SharpDevelop it was a no-brainer for us.

As a specific example, one thing we found that SharpDevelop didn't convert correctly was VB indexes, which use curvy brackets. It seemed unable to distinguish between indexes and method calls so didn't convert the indexes to square brackets. VBConversions converted them fine. This one thing made it worth its purchase for us.

It looks like [Tangible Software](http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/) have a very similarly product to VBConversions, but I don't have any experience with it. [Jon Skeet suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355340/convert-vb-net-c-sharp-projects/355505#355505) it though, so it must be pretty good.